# Destroy DIVs with their IDs containing a particular string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some DIVs with IDs like 'abc_chosen', 'danger_chosen', etc.

I would like to delete all DIVs when their IDs contain the string '_chosen'.

How can I do that?

Comment: With or without jQuery?

Comment: with jquery. That will be best

Comment: look in the jQuery selectors API ... would have found answer as fast as creating this question..and might have learned something at the same time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div[id$="_chosen"]').remove();
```

`$` here will check if `_chosen` is at the end of `id`.

Thanks to @evolutionxbox:
If you want to check if id contain `_chosen` anywhere(not at the end)

```
$('[id*="_chosen"]').remove();
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: You could also try `$('[id*="_chosen"]').remove();` where the `*` matches `_chosen` in any part of the ID string.

Comment: @evolutionxbox The OP didn't mention this case, also the examples are ending with `_chosen`

Comment: Maybe not, but it's still good to know.